# How to download part of a React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a website builder using React and I want to be able to download the content of this component under the `preview-container` class.
`MainWebsite` contains multiple descendants and components.

```
export default function PreviewContainer({
    selectItem
}) {
    return (
        <div className="preview-container" >
            <div className="preview">
                <MainWebsite selectItem={selectItem}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I tried using

```
function onClick() {
        var pageHTML = document.querySelector('.preview-container');
        var tempEl = document.createElement('a');
        tempEl.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(pageHTML);
        tempEl.target = '_blank';
        tempEl.download = 'thispage.html';
        tempEl.click();
    }
```

This downloads a page that just says `[object HTMLDivElement]` in its content
Note though that I want to download this component with the css and js included

Comment: *But this doesn't work*. What's not working? Is it not downloading anything?

Comment: It'd be better to have `pageHTML` in the state instead of directly accessing the DOM in react.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't download an abstract element.

You'll need the [inner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) or [outer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) HTML of the element, depending on your requirements. (You could also use [`ReactDOMServer.renderToString()`](http://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring).)

Additionally, you should use [a blob URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL), since the HTML could be quite large and thus awkward to put in a data URL.

If you use a blob URL, it needs to be revoked (to release memory). Some browsers require an anchor element to be in the DOM when "clicked", so that needs to be removed too. Since there's no event for "download complete", there's a simple timeout for 2 seconds.

```
function onClick() {
  const pageHTML = document.querySelector(".preview-container").outerHTML;
  const blob = new Blob([pageHTML], { type: "text/html" });
  const url = URL.createObjectUrl(blob);
  const tempEl = document.createElement("a");
  document.body.appendChild(tempEl);
  tempEl.href = url;
  tempEl.download = "thispage.html";
  tempEl.click();
  setTimeout(() => {
    URL.revokeObjectUrl(url);
    tempEl.parentNode.removeChild(tempEl);
  }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The one thing was that I had to  do was change `URL`  to `window.URL` . But i assume css cant be downloaded if it was created in the project instead of imported with cdn link

Comment: Not necessarily. See e.g. [`document.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets)...

Comment: @AKX I know you answered this a while ago, but I'm having trouble seeing how document.styleSheets could be used to apply styling to the downloaded file. Would it be possible to provide an example in your post, using OP's example?

Comment: @penguin I think I may have been referring to being able to use `document.styleSheets` to grab the contents of included styles and stuff them in the same HTML, but that's not going to be bulletproof.